PySpark: Most efficient way to drop duplicates based on subset of columns on a very large table
I have a table that looks like this:



src
dst
type




2
1
A


2
1
B


3
2
T


4
3
B


4
3
T



I would like to keep one row per src & dst pair. That is:



src
dst




2
1


3
2


4
3



This table has billions of rows and I'm looking for the most efficient way to achieve this.
Option 1 - dropDuplicates
df = df.dropDuplicates(subset=['src', 'dst'])

Option 2 - groupBy + First
df = df.groupBy('src', 'dst').select(
    F.first('src').alias('src'),
    F.first('dst').alias('dst')
)

I suppose I could also use row_number to partition by src and dst, randomly sort the partitions and keep their first record.
What's the most efficient way to do this?
